# Raspberry pi 3 b+ and 7" touchscreen over poe

Tags: power, power-supply, pi-3b+, touchscreen, poe

I have an issue, i want to power my pi and 7" touchscreen over poe but the raspberry pi poe hat supplies only 2.5 amp.

7" touchscreen requires 2.5 amp and rpi 3 b+ also requires 2.5 amp so i am in need of a poe hat that supplies 5 amp.

So far i did not even find a poe module that can supply 5v 25w the closest on from silvertel gives 5w 13w or 12v 30-ish w.

Is there any module that can do that or i am stuck with 12v 30w module plus a dc/dc module 12v to 5v?

Many thanks!

Comment: According to https://www.adafruit.com/product/2718 the display and pi together can be run on a single 2A supply. However it is not clear if the POE hat will include a connection that can be used to power the display.

Comment: The display can be powered form pi expansion header or from usb out (not shure if it can supply enough amps). So far my testing shows that if i power the display and pi from 3 amp usb psu the pi shows under volt so i assumed that it useses mor amps than psu can supply.

Answer (score 2):

I use this PoE Splitter with the Raspberry Pi 3B+, but should work with any version of Pi.  In the config shown in attached pictures, I connected the MicroUSB power cable into the female part of the power cable which branches to both the Pi and the 7" LCD touchscreen display.  The PoE Splitter supplies sufficient power to drive both the Pi and the Touchscreen display.  Would work with just a Pi connected via HDMI to a standard monitor (no Touchscreen). I actually bought this as a workaround because the PoE hat won't fit in the Smarti Pi Touchscreen case for the Official 7" display.  NOTE:  Although the link indicator shows orange (10/100 speed), the GB model does connect at 1000 MB/sec speed.  I checked both the switch which reported GB speed and I also checked from Linux to see what speed the connection was and this too reported 1000/MB/sec (see second picture).  So you'll see a FAST Ethernet light instead of the expected GREEN one for GB speeds on the PoE splitter, but ignore it.  It works at the advertised speed for this model.  Further note:  This company sells a 10/100 model of the same PoE Splitter, so validate you are buying the GB speed splitter. Bought the PoE Splitter on Amazon.co.uk for £9.90 inc VAT[image: Connections][image: Connection Speed]

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully run the official POE Hat and the official touchscreen.  It would only work if I ran the screen off the GPIO 5v/Ground GPIO pins to the screen, which required a GPIO pin extender module (so the pins push through the POE HAT).  I've seen notes online that some people have soldered the 5v/ground pins from the bottom of the Pi to make for a clean install.  I did find that the POE provided 'just enough' power - I would not suggest running any high amperage USB device.

The USB port power did not work, and I believe it is because the touchscreen had to wait for the POE hat to powerup the Pi enough to provide power to the USB ports, but missed the critical window where the Pi identified it was connected to the touchscreen.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear that there's a "critical window" to connect a USB HID to a Linux computer. I'm pretty sure any Linux distro that's less than 10 years old can handle them being connected and disconnected anytime.

Comment: The touchscreen isn't a USB device, though. All of its connections are over that flat cable (the USB is power-only), and something in there doesn't seem to get connected if it's not there on boot. I suspect that the designers, since the cable's not really designed to be plugged in/unplugged easily, didn't bother to add a hotplug mode to the screen drivers.